# Unable to XMLSerialize a class generated from xsd.exe which has enum

Tags: c#, xml, enums, xsd

I have generated classes  for an xsd file using xsd.exe  **which have reference to other xsd file i.e link** using below command

```
xsd.exe file1.xsd linkfile.xsd /c
```

Classes are generated , but in file1.xsd I have  a complextype as

```
<xsd:complexType name="Department">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Uses xlink: attributes to connect locations in the document or at any URL by defining an arc and arc type and role.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:attributeGroup ref="xlink:deptLink"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="SequenceNumber" type="xsd:integer">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>An integer value used to provide an order to multi-instance sibling elements.</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

the xlink:deptLink i.e deptLink complextype is in the linkfile.xsd file , so when I genearte classes using the command mentioned above its is creating a field of type enum inside Department class.

So when I try to generate xml using

```
XmlSerializer serailizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainClass));
```

I'm getting error as

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There was an error reflecting type 'MainClass'.

Comment: In order to help, we need a full [mcve] that includes the XSD files that cause the problem.  See [ask].  You should also include the full `ToString()` output of the exception include the message, traceback, exception type *and inner exception*.  Often the inner exception explains the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual inner exception is very deep i.e in to many layers of inner exception and finally it was

**The global XML attribute 'type' from namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' references distinct types deptLink and orgLink . Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the attribute or types.**

The xlink.xsd which I was using have two -xsd attributes with name "type"

I have given distinct names and it is working fine